# How to escape a forward slash in sphinx wordforms?

Tags: escaping, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx as a search engine for a music store.
There are some band names that could be searched in various ways and I used wordforms to map them to a common form.

Now the problem is with ac/dc, I want to map them to ac dc (with a space) and I had no problems with ac-dc ac\dc and so on. But I can't manage to have ac/dc to be mapped correctly. I read that the / character is used to escape a space, but how to escape / itself? I tried with \ and \ but with no avail.

Comment: Do you actully have / in your charset table? if not, then its already been stripped by the time get to wordform processing, so you dont need it.

Comment: I added it to charset table, Now when I launch the indexer I don't have complaints anymore about wordforms, but still the search fails to succeed. If I try from mysql I get `syntax error, unexpected '/' near '/dc'`